# redirect http to https OS X Server 5.0.15

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, ssl, https

I have 2 domain names: users.newsite.com and users.oldsite.com.  I have users.newsite.com hosted on Mac OS X 10.10.5 using Server version 5.0.15.  I have A records setup in DNS so that both domain names (users.newsite.com and users.oldsite.com) point to the same IP address for the OS X Server machine.

We have a wildcard SSL cert of *.newsite.com and the cert is installed on the OS X Server machine.  I have a redirect configured in OS X Server (I believe this uses Apache) so all traffic for the http version of users.newsite.com is going to the https version of users.newsite.com.  This is working properly.

The problem is if anyone uses http version of users.oldsite.com.  They get a warning that the connection is not secure because their browser is trying to redirect to https version of users.oldsite.com.  We do not have an SSL cert for oldsite.com.

Is there a way to setup a redirect so that any traffic coming from http://users.* (newsite or oldsite) gets redirected to https version of users.newsite.com?

I can enter a URL matching a regular expression and direct that in the Server app, but I don't know what to enter to get the redirect to work properly so that the http versions of users.newsite.com AND users.oldsite.com both redirect to the https version of users.newsite.com.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a great question. Unfortunately, this is the wrong site for it.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect users from https oldsite.com you must have a valid certificate for oldsite.com (the same for subdomains).